# Can't perform any action in the new close vote queue

Tags: support

I can no longer take any action on a post up for review in the new close vote queue. I am using a rather old browser (Safari 11.1), so maybe I am one of few affected. Is anyone elese having this problem?

P.S. Voting to close in the question still works for me because it still displays the old close vote dialog.

Comment: It appears to be working for me (Safari 14.0.2) Is using Chrome an option if you can't upgrade your macOS/Safari?

Comment: @rn. I am not surprised to learn it works on newer versions of Safari. Chrome in not an option. I have seen posts saying it doesn't work at all with MacOS 10.13, which is what I running because my computer is too old to run any later release. I'm afraid I am going to have buy an new computer before I am functional again on this site. There are a number of other issues with other sites also pushing me in that direction.